# How to break a very long gantt chart into consecutive lines?

Tags: pgfgantt

I need a gantt chart for a project in a long period of time like over a year.

Consider the following `MWE`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{capt-of} %caption outside floats
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
        \captionof{figure}{My Timeline}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{ganttchart}[%%%
        hgrid,
        vgrid,
        x unit=4mm,
        time slot format=isodate,
        title/.append style={shape=rectangle, fill=black!10},
        title height=1,
        bar/.append style={fill=green!70},
        bar height=.6,
        bar label font=\normalsize\color{black!90},
        group top shift=.6,
        group height=.3,
        group peaks height=.2,
        ]{2017-04-01}{2018-08-01}
        14
        \gantttitlecalendar{year, month, day} \\
        \ganttbar{Task}{2018-05-15}{2018-05-25}                    
        \end{ganttchart}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to break the gannt chart into many consecutive lines to cover all the target period?

Comment: I think you have to do it manually,  by making several charts one after the other.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Maybe. But that would be much complicated to maintain.

Comment: Yes, but if no automatic way is described in the manual, then my guess is that it's the only way.